# AngularJS - ng-repeat when value starts with 'X'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a $scope object:

```
"MyData": [
    {
        "CompareCode" : "A004",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    },
    {
        "CompareCode" : "X084",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    },
    {
        "CompareCode" : "A1025",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    },
    {
        "CompareCode" : "A1",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    },
    {
        "CompareCode" : "X52",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    },
    {
        "CompareCode" : "A541",
        "CompareMessage" : "test test test, test test test",
    }
]
```

Want to perform an `ng-repeat` but filter it on all items where CompareCode starts with an A.

I have tried:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in MyData | filter="data.CompareCode.indexOf('A')"">
    {{ data.CompareMessage }}
</li>
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: your html is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in MyData | filter: { CompareCode:'A' } ">
    {{ data.CompareMessage }}
</li>
```

Comment: This will show all CompareCode that contain 'A', not just start with. So, 'XAX' will also match.

Comment: I assumed this by the use of indexOf in the original post

Comment: Ah, I see, but still worth mentioning as people that come later may get confused!

Answer (score 2):

Your html is invalid.

```
<li ng-repeat="data in MyData | filter="data.CompareCode.indexOf('A')"">
   {{ data.CompareMessage }}
</li>
```

should be

```
<li ng-repeat="data in MyData | filter: { CompareCode:'A' } ">
    {{ data.CompareMessage }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `filter` method:

```
 $scope.getFilteredData = function(){
  return $scope.data.filter(function(item){
        return item.CompareCode.indexOf('A') === 0;
    });
}
```

and HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in getFilteredData()">
    {{ data.CompareMessage }}
</li>
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1934/)</kbd>

Comment: `> -1` has the same result as filter btw, I think you wanted `=== 0` for starts with

Comment: @Blowsie right, it the same like use `| filter`, however for better maintenance I would use this way. In addition I posted this answer as different way (from yours) :)

Comment: the point I was trying top make here is all of the other answers are incorrect as they just check to see if it includes `A` and not starts with.

Answer (score 1):

You may use ng-if to check for the first character:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in myData" ng-if="data.CompareCode.indexOf('A') == 0">
    <span>{{ data.CompareMessage }}</span>
</li>
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pwap3/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own filter:

http://jsbin.com/mebucude/13/edit

```
$scope.myFilter = function (word) {
if(word.CompareCode.charAt(0)=='A'){
  return word.CompareMessage;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in MyData | filter: myFilter ">
{{ data.CompareMessage }} </li>
```